# android unable to build the project showing install missing files

Tags: android, ide

Codes of build.gradle(Module.app)
After,creating my project it was showing incompatible version.So,Found in internet to modify my gradle file but after modifying gradle file and changing compile sdk from 26  to 27 it's showing install the missing file .

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.thelost.fisp_beta10"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:27.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Error: Showing in my project

[image]

Comment: Click on the error . You probably missing API27  . Click on error it will install.

Comment: Thanks for helping .I will give a try.

Answer (score 1):

Click on the error if any, it will automatically download.

From the [docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/build-tools.html)

> You should always keep your Build Tools component updated by
>   downloading the latest version using the Android SDK Manager. If
>   you're using Android plugin for Gradle 3.0.0 or higher, your project
>   automatically uses a default version of the build tools that the
>   plugin specifies. To use a different version of the build tools,
>   specify it using buildToolsVersion in your module's build.gradle,

The latest `buildToolsVersion` is `27.0.1`

So change

```
buildToolsVersion "27.0.2"
```

to

```
buildToolsVersion "27.0.1"
```

and sync your project.

Answer (score 1):

try this in app level gradle

```
repositories {
   maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
     }
}
```